# QAOA not returning solution for simple clustering problem

Tags: programming, qiskit, optimization, qaoa

I am following University's of toronto QML course and there's a section where QAOA is applied to cluster a set of vectors by mapping the clustering problem into a Maxcut problem. Unfortunately qiskit's QAOA is not returning the right solution (even within the course's notebook lecture), so I am a bit lost in the implementation.

The (4) points are (top two are on the top left corner and bottom two on the bottom right corner)

```
data = array([[ 0.11 ,  0.143],
       [ 0.121,  0.109],
       [-1.515,  1.629],
       [-1.512,  1.678]])
```

And the distance matrix (used as the 'weight' matrix of the maxcut graph) is

```
w = array([[0.   , 0.   , 2.202, 2.234],
   [0.   , 0.   , 2.233, 2.265],
   [2.202, 2.233, 0.   , 0.   ],
   [2.234, 2.265, 0.   , 0.   ]])
```

(distances < 0.5 were mapped to 0 as pre-processing).

Using Qiskit's `max_cut class`, we map `w` into an Ising problem. We also verify the best solution

```
qubit_operators, offset = max_cut.get_max_cut_qubitops(-w)
// checking for solutions (cleary 0011 and 1100 are the solutions)
(0, 0, 0, 0) 4.466870101471442
(0, 0, 0, 1) 0.031168254348417523
(0, 0, 1, 0) -0.031168254348417523
(0, 0, 1, 1) -4.466870101471442
(0, 1, 0, 0) 0.03160476231770515
(0, 1, 0, 1) 0.0001477223286934226
(0, 1, 1, 0) -0.0001477223286934226
(0, 1, 1, 1) -0.03160476231770515
(1, 0, 0, 0) -0.03160476231770515
(1, 0, 0, 1) -0.0001477223286934226
(1, 0, 1, 0) 0.0001477223286934226
(1, 0, 1, 1) 0.03160476231770515
(1, 1, 0, 0) -4.466870101471442
(1, 1, 0, 1) -0.031168254348417523
(1, 1, 1, 0) 0.031168254348417523
(1, 1, 1, 1) 4.466870101471442
```

after inputting the mapped operator and running it on Qiskit's QAOA

```
from qiskit.aqua import get_aer_backend, QuantumInstance
from qiskit.aqua.algorithms import QAOA
from qiskit.aqua.components.optimizers import COBYLA
from qiskit.aqua.translators.ising import max_cut

p = 1

#w = -w
qubit_operators, offset = max_cut.get_max_cut_qubitops(-w)
p = 1
optimizer = COBYLA()
qaoa = QAOA(qubit_operators, optimizer, p)
backend = get_aer_backend('statevector_simulator')
quantum_instance = QuantumInstance(backend, shots=10)
result = qaoa.run(quantum_instance)
```

The output is the following:

```
{'num_optimizer_evals': 13,
 'min_val': 0.0,
 'opt_params': array([0., 0.]),
 'eval_time': 0.32109689712524414,
 'eval_count': 13,
 'energy': 0.0,
 'eigvals': array([0.]),
 'min_vector': array([0.25+0.j, 0.25+0.j, 0.25+0.j, 0.25+0.j, 0.25+0.j, 0.25+0.j,
        0.25+0.j, 0.25+0.j, 0.25+0.j, 0.25+0.j, 0.25+0.j, 0.25+0.j,
        0.25+0.j, 0.25+0.j, 0.25+0.j, 0.25+0.j]),
 'eigvecs': array([[0.25+0.j, 0.25+0.j, 0.25+0.j, 0.25+0.j, 0.25+0.j, 0.25+0.j,
         0.25+0.j, 0.25+0.j, 0.25+0.j, 0.25+0.j, 0.25+0.j, 0.25+0.j,
         0.25+0.j, 0.25+0.j, 0.25+0.j, 0.25+0.j]])}
```

It seems as if the QAOA never evolves (optimal $\gamma$ and $\beta$ are 0) and stays in the mixer's ground state.

Has anyone experienced the same problem?

I'm using Qiskit's 0.9.0 (otherwise code is not compatible with the course).

Answer (score 2):

There was an issue that was fixed with QAOA https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua/pull/1316 whereby using all zeros as an initial point was changed since the optimizer could easily get stuck there.

Given the version you have the easiest way to change things would just be to pass an initial point that is non-zero. I.e. instead of [0,0] which it uses with the default of None set it to some other value e.g.

> qaoa = QAOA(qubit_operators, optimizer, p, initial_point=[1, 0.5])

or some other value where you will see it works and does no get stuck

Comment: This makes sense, since $|0\rangle^n$ is indeed an eigenstate. But isn't the point of the mixer is to help to avoid such local minimum in the first place? I don't know what type of circuit is the OP used but I am assuming it's a typical QAOA circuit deriving from the discretization of the  adiabatic quantum annealing process.